# How to make an animation out of images represented by numpy arrays in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am currently processing some images using numpy and I'm storing the new arrays with the results in dictionaries. An example of the images is below:

[image]

Once I have the dictionary with the results, that are also images, how can I make a movie sequence of them? Using this I intend to observe how the structures evolve in time.

My attempt to achieve this is represented below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def init(img):
    '''
    This function supports the ''make_anim'' function by plotting the
    background of each frame
    '''
    img.set_data([],[])

    return(img)


def updatefig(data, keys, i):
    '''
    This function supports the ''make_anim'' function by refreshing the 
    image space.
    '''

    img.set_data(data[keys[i]])

    return(img)

def make_anim(data, keys = []):
    '''
    This function will produce an animation from a dataset.
    '''
    if keys == []:
        keys = list(data.keys())

    dims = data[keys[0]].shape

    #defining the figure
    fig = plt.figure()

    #defining axis
    ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, dims[1]), ylim=(0, dims[0]))

    #inserting the dataset to an image
    img = plt.imgshow(data, animated = True)
    #using the animation function
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig(data, keys), 
                                  interval = 50,
                                  frames = len(keys), blit = False)
    plt.show()

    return()
```

I'm struggling to find tutorials that deal with similar problems and when I find them I can't really reproduce.

Thanks for your time in advance!

Andre

Comment: [You mean like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23176161/8881141) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34975972/8881141)?