# Animation of Precomputed Interactive Graphs Using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I created several plots using the following code:

```
a = np.arange(1,6)
b = np.arange(2, 11, 2)
c = np.arange(100, 1000, 200)
d = np.arange(0.2, 1.1, 0.2)
figs = []
for i in np.arange(1, 6):   
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.bar(a, b/i, width = d/10)
    ax.scatter(a, b/i, s=c*i)
    figs.append(fig)

fig = plt.figure()
ani = matplotlib.animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, figs)
plt.show()
```

And the graphs look like [image: this]

I put the figure objects into a list and used the ArtistAnimation feature, but nothing seems to show. I'm also adding interactive features to each graph such as hover boxes so I can't just save the plots and make gifs. Can someone point out where I need to change my code? Also, is there any way to turn off the display of graphs when I generate them so that there won't be too many different graphs displaying at the same time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Animating pngs in matplotlib using ArtistAnimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176161/animating-pngs-in-matplotlib-using-artistanimation)

Comment: You are not using ArtistAnimation correctly. Try to find a working example, e.g. the one in my comment above. `np.append` is for arrays, not for lists. A list also has `.append`